How long would a satellite remain in orbit at the Karman Line?
Satellites in LEO spontaneously de-orbit due to atmospheric drag. For instance, the ISS will de-orbit in a few years without regular boosts.
How long would a typical satellite (say, a Starlink satellite) remain in orbit at the Karman Line altitude (100 km) without boosting? Would this be measured in orbits, days or weeks?
Here is a photo of starship at the Karman line. Looks like it has significant drag.


Closely related, but not a duplicate: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/61414/using-2023-technology-how-low-can-a-satellite-orbit-earth

Interesting & related news article - they briefly mention altitudes as low as 90 km as well as potentially air-breathing electric thrusters

@fyrepenguin - sort of orbiting, they will be using a small amount of constant thrust to maintain orbit at 90 km. Just like would be needed at 100 km where thrust is required to overcome drag and maintain orbital velocity. You have to be above probably about 120 km (actual altitude varies as is being currently discussed) to maintain circular orbit for  more than a few orbits without thrust.

@StevePemberton yup. Not an answer (since it explicitly calls for no boosting), but something I found interesting and fairly relevant since it’s intended to be more than short-term orbits at a similar altitude as in the question.

@fyrepenguin - Yes it is an interesting concept. They will be dealing with a bit of constant heat orbiting at 90 km.

This page allows you to estimate orbital decay based on altitude, and satellite area and mass. For a satellite at 100 km I get a lifetime of one day.
I seem to remember it's less than that: once you get to ~120 km, you'll deorbit within one orbit. Looking for a reference for this.
This page has a graph that shows orbit lifetimes.

These are averages: lifetime depends on the amount of drag the satellite experiences (which depends on frontal area, drag coefficient, wetted area etc.), the mass of the satellite, and on the state of the atmosphere.

Good answer but may be worth including the fact that the atmosphere changes size over time meaning the decay rate at any given altitude will vary. https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2022SW003330

@Saiboogu at 100 km specifically, is there really much variation in density?

@uhoh Yes, there's significant relative variation in the density in the thermosphere, mostly due to solar heating. There's some info in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_tide although the equations there mostly focus on temperature rather than density.

@PM2Ring but quantitatively, how large is this (or any other) density variation specifically at 100 km? 10%? 1%? 0.1%? Is the change anywhere large enough to have a significant effect on the rate of descent of a re-entering object passing the Karman line? Even the position of Neptune makes a difference, but we don't bring it up because it's not significant.

@uhoh Sorry, no idea, which is why I just posted a comment, not an answer. It would be great to have some quantitative info, but I figured some qualitative info was better than nothing. ;)

@uhoh It makes a massive difference. If I remember correctly, at 100 km it can vary by more than an order of magnitude depending on solar activity, time of day, time of year, latitude and so on. You can try one of the online models (MSIS-E-90 or NRLMSISE-00, both seem to require free registration these days) for various input parameters and write out density at 100 km.

@Martin'Kvík'Baláž [citation needed]

@uhoh I agree, but I do not have time to do this right now: feel free to explore the model at https://www.ukssdc.ac.uk/cgi-bin/wdcc1/secure/msis_models.pl
I was able to find values between 2.887e-13 and 7.747e-13 g/cm³ manually, so just a little bit short of 1:e.
